# this semi clean getx pattern is good or bad?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently trying to use the getx pattern with get_cli like this

https://pastebin.com/tAUrR22h

```
  inside the primary controller to access sub controller
      TodoGet? _todoGet;
      TodoGet get todoGet => _todoGet ??= TodoGet(this);
     
      TodoDelete? _todoDelete;
      TodoDelete get todoDelete => _todoDelete ??= TodoDelete(this);



 sub controller
    class TodoGet {
      final ExampleController controller;
      
      TodoGet(this.controller);
     
      /// getting data from api
      getData() async => await ApiRequest.Get();
    }
     
    class TodoDelete {
      final ExampleController controller;
      TodoDelete(this.controller);
     
      /// delete all todo data from list [TodoStates]
      deleteAllData() {
        controller.stateTodo.data.clear();
        controller.update(['todo']);
      }
    }
```

by creating subcontrollers for each function such as get data or delete and using them in controller modules generated by get_cli. At first glance this is because it's inspired by BLoC clean architecture, I wanted to learn about it, but it just took time, so I tried GetX, what's wrong with this kind of approach, and if there's a better one, please share. Thank You

[image]